# React 17: how to pass an event handler in a Router <LINK> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass an event handler via a `<LINK>` tag. My ultimate objective is to pass the event handler to a child component:

```
<Post post={post} onClickClose={props.onClickClose} />
```

Because I am using a router, I cannot pass the event handler, using a standard prop. I am sure there must be a solution to this problem, because this seems like a fairly normal feature.

**App Description:**

1. The ToDo List allows the user to delete each ToDo
2. The ToDo List allows the user to navigate to each individual post
3. Each individual post allows the user to delete itself, using the same method reference as the ToDo List has access to

**App hierarchy:**

```
App
- Header
- - NotFound
- - ToDoList *
- - - Post **
- - Posts
- - - ToDoList *
- - - - ToDo **

** Ref: onClickClose -> removeTodo

* Method: removeTodo
```

Here is a very short version of my code:

**SET UP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  
    <script src="assets/babel/bbh.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.3.1/umd/react-router-dom.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div id="app">
    
      <script type="text/babel" name="react-example">
      
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { render } from 'react-dom';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import { welcome } from './bbh';
        
        const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
        const NavLink = ReactRouterDOM.NavLink;
        const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
        const Switch = ReactRouterDOM.Switch;
        const Router = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
        const Redirect = ReactRouterDOM.Redirect;
        
        // ToDo class component
        
        class ToDo extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          }
          render() {
            const link = "/post/" + this.props.slug;
            return (
              <Link to={
                {
                  pathname: link,
                  state: {
                    onClickClose: this.props.onClickClose
                  }
                }
              }>
                  My Link
              </Link>
            )
          }
        }
        
        /*
          Other class components:

          App
          Post
          Posts
          NotFound
          ToDoList
          
        */
        
        // Header class component
        
        class Header extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              posts: [
                {
                  id: 1,
                  slug: "hello-react",
                  title: "Hello React",
                  content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                  done: true,
                  createdAt: dateFns.format(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                },
                {
                  id: 2,
                  slug: "hello-project",
                  title: "Hello Project",
                  content: "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ",
                  done: true,
                  createdAt: dateFns.format(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                },
                {
                  id: 3,
                  slug: "hello-blog",
                  title: "Hello Blog",
                  content: "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
                  done: true,
                  createdAt: dateFns.format(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                },
              ]
            };
          }
          render() {
            return (
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Posts posts={this.state.posts} />} />
                <Route path="/post/:postSlug" render={(props) => {
                  console.log("props ",props);
                  const post = this.state.posts.find(
                    (post) => post.slug === props.match.params.postSlug
                  );
                  if (post) return 
                    <Post post={post} onClickClose={props.onClickClose} />
                    // ERROR
                  else return 
                    <NotFound />
                }}
                />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            )
          }
        }
        
        render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
      
      </script>
    
    </div>
    
    <script>
      bbh.babelConfig = {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread'],
        minified: true
      } 
    </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, I get an error.

It seems like I can pass anything in LINK -> to.state, except for an event handler?

I have also tried creating a standard prop  in the LINK tag, like:

```
<Link onClickClose={this.props.onClickClose} to={link}>
    My Link
</Link>
```

But, the **onClickClose prop** is not passed through to the router?

Can anyone provide a solution for passing an event handler in a LINK tag?

**Environment:**

- Windows 10
- React 17
- react-router-dom 4.3.1

**NOTES:**

The reason, I am using **react-router-dom 4.3.1**, is that this was the only CDN router version that worked properly. I am using the CDN versions, because I am trying to display this on **codepen.io**

**UPDATE:**

codepen.io

https://codepen.io/charles1971/pen/GRjOVzz

Comment: use context to achieve it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot (and should not!) pass non-serializable objects to `state` in React Router. In browsers, it uses the history API which itself requires that state is serializable (which functions are not).

If you are attempting to *intercept* the behaviour of a link (for example, to cancel navigation to the link) you can do that just fine with `onClick`.  However, it looks more like you're trying to instruct your code to take a certain action after performing an action on a different page.

It looks like you're trying to simulate navigation using links - why not just *use* links and anchors rather than trying to use onClick handlers? For example, instead of passing a callback as a property, pass a URL (or object) that the next page should visit after the task completion.

Responding to your comments:

> The problem is, that the child is on the other side of a router.

In short, no. You're not defining a parent-child relationship here. At least in the code you've listed, you've' defined `ToDo`, which is a `<Link>` that will *link* you to a child. The render tree could be more accurately represented like this:

```
<Header>
  <Router>
    <Route>
      <Posts>
        <ToDo>
        <ToDo>
        <ToDo>
      </Posts>
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <Post>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Header>
```

As you can see from the above code, what you have is not actually a parent-child relationship (despite the components being nominally related), but a sibling-to-sibling relationship. There are a couple of ways you could achieve what you're trying to do. The *easiest* way would be to use Links in both routes - you might, for example, have a link to each post in the `<Posts>` component and then a `<Link>` to the `<Posts>` route in the each `<Post>` route:

```
// In <Posts>
<ul>
  {posts.map(p => <li><Link to={`/posts/${p.id}`} /></li>)}
</ul>

// In <Post>
<div>
  <Link to='/posts'>Back</Link>
   .... Content of the post
</div>
```

There's no need to make this much more complicated than using simple links and that's how users expect websites to work anyway :)

If you don't want to hard-code the location of the index page in `<Post>` - which is understandable - you could instead use location state. But keep in mind that this obscures the flow of the application a bit and won't work with regular anchors (which means that users who visit your website from a bookmark or refresh might get a slightly different experience):

```
const ToDo = ({ returnURL }) => {
  return <Link to={{ pathname: link, state: { returnURL  }} />
}

const Post = ({ defaultReturnURL }) => {
  const loc = useLocation();
  const returnURL = loc.state.returnURL ?? "/posts";
  return <div>
    <Link to={returnURL}>Back to Posts</Link>
    ....
  </div>  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Thanks for clearing up the fact about not being able to pass non-serializable objects via a React Router. I never knew this. I am actually trying to pass an event handler reference from parent to child. The problem is, that the child is on the other side of a router. Normally, I could just pass it from parent to child via attributes & props, but because I am using a link [todo component: parent] to access the child [post component: child], this is not possible?

Comment: What I am saying is that I must use the React Router methodology. And I must use <LINK to=“”>

Comment: I've updated my answer, but based on what I'm seeing I don't think you need to pass functions around

Comment: Dan. I am considering your comments, but, in the meantime, I have added the full code in a codepen link. Please see updated question. The ToDo List allows the user to delete each ToDo, but if you click on the link icon, it takes you to the individual post. Here you can delete the post, using the trash can icon. It uses the same ToDoList.removeTodo method, which I need to access. This is why I need to pass the function reference around...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED PEN:**

https://codepen.io/charles1971/pen/GRjOVzz

**SOLUTION:**

The solution to this problem is to reference the `<ToDoList />` component, twice, from within two different components.

The `<ToDoList />` component contains the **removeToDo** method. Somehow, we need to be able to use this method in two different places. The `<ToDoList />` component needs to be referenced from  both the `<Posts />` component and the `<Header />` component.

It is then neccessary to add two new props to the `<ToDoList />` component:

**New Props**

**origin**

Defines the origin of where the component is being referenced from

**id**

Identifies the current active post's link

**Before**

```
<ToDoList posts="" />
```

**After**

```
<ToDoList posts="" origin="" id="" />
```

Now,it is possible to leverage these new props to make use of a ternary operator in the **render** method of the `<ToDoList />` component.

**ToDoList render method**

... represents extra HTML code

```
render{
    let todos = null;
    if(this.props.origin == "posts"){
        todos = this.state.todos.map(
          function (todo, index) {
            return (
              <ToDo 
                key={index} 
                keyRef={index} 
                ref={index} 
                title={todo.title} 
                done={todo.done} 
                slug={todo.slug} 
                onClickClose={this.removeTodo.bind(this,index,"posts")}
                onClickDone={this.markTodoDone.bind(this,index)}
                onClickUp={this.move.bind(this,index,"up")}
                onClickDown={this.move.bind(this,index,"down")}
              />
            );
          }.bind(this)
        );
    }
    else{
        todos = this.state.todos.map(
          function (todo, index) {
            return (
              <Post 
                key={index} 
                keyRef={index} 
                ref={index} 
                title={todo.title} 
                done={todo.done} 
                slug={todo.slug} 
                createdAt={todo.createdAt} 
                content={todo.content} 
                id1={this.props.id} 
                id2={todo.id} 
                onClickClose={this.removeTodo.bind(this,index,"post")}
              />
            );
          }.bind(this)
        );
    }
    return (
        this.state.redirect == false ? (
      this.props.origin == "posts" ? 
            (
                ...
                {todos}
                ...
            )
            :
            (
                ...
                {todos}
                ...
            )
        )
        :
        (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        )
    )
}
```

The **redirect** is used, after the delete routine has finished in the `<Post />` component. This will return the user to the **ToDoList** section of the router. Obviously, it doesn't look good, to leave the user looking at a blank section of the router, that has just been deleted!

So, now the **Switch** part of the `<Header />` component, looks like:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => <Posts posts={this.state.posts} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/post/:postSlug"
    render={(props) => {
      const post = this.state.posts.find(
        (post) => post.slug === props.match.params.postSlug
      );
      if (post)
        return (
                <ToDoList origin="post" posts={this.state.posts} id={post.id} />
        );
      else return <NotFound />;
    }}
  />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

And, the `<Posts />` component looks like:

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  }
  render() {
    return <ToDoList origin="posts" posts={this.props.posts} id="" />;
  }
}
```

And, finally, the `<Post />` component looks like:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  }
  render() {
    const display = this.props.id1 == this.props.id2 ? "block" : "none";
    const defaultStyle1 = {
      display: display
    };
    const defaultStyle2 = {
      padding: "20px"
    };
    return (
      <div className="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" style={defaultStyle1}>
        <div className="mdl-card__title post">
          <h2 className="mdl-card__title-text">{this.props.title}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mdl-card__supporting-text">
          {this.props.createdAt}
          <i className="fa fa-trash" onClick={this.props.onClickClose}></i>
        </div>
        <div className="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
          <div className="todo-container" style={defaultStyle2}>
            {this.props.content}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Two **id** props are sent to the `<Post />` component, from the `<ToDoList />` component. This allows the correct **post** to be displayed to the screen. All the posts are actually rendered, but only one of them will have their CSS **display** property set to **block**. The rest are set to **none**. Now, the **onClickClose** prop [an alias for **removeToDo** method] can be passed to the `<Post />` component, which allows the user to delete posts from the post section of the router. Each post can also be deleted from the **ToDoList** section of the router, using the same **removeToDo** method.